# Add / delete / retrieve information from a PDF using a custom property

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Sorry for the unclear question yesterday i post. I want to store 2 strings(string1 and string2) in the custom property,so that the string is with the pdf.I have the string already, but i do not know how to store it under the custom property area. The custom property area refers to  FILE--->Properties---->Custom ---->Custom properties , which got "Name" and "Value" in pairs. I want the string1 stores in the "Value" and string2 stores in the "Name".

Later, I want to retrieve/delete the strings in the custom property area.
May I ask how to achieve it with itext?

Thanks and Regards,

Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for clarifying. Based on your description on how to add the data you want using Acrobat, we now know that you were referring to metadata.

I've used Acrobat to add a custom metadata entry named "Test" with value "test" and when you look inside that file, you can see that this key/value pair turns up on two places (marked with a red dot):

[image]

1. It is present in the Info dictionary, which is the *traditional* place to store metadata.
2. It is present in the XMP metadata stream as a tag named Test with prefix pdfx (for custom tags).

Adding an extra value to the Info dictionary is easy when using iText. Updating the XMP metadata is also possible, but you'll have to create the XMP stream yourself and maybe it's overkill in your case. Maybe your PDF only has an Info dictionary and no XMP.

Moreover: you say that the purpose of having that key is to retrieve its value and to delete the custom entry afterwards. In that case, it's sufficient to add the extra entry in the Info dictionary.

Depending on whether you want to add a custom entry to the Info dictionary to a PDF created from scratch or to an existing PDF you need one of the following examples:

In [CustomMetaEntry](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/objects/CustomMetaEntry), we add a standard metadata entry for the title and a custom entry named Test:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.addTitle("Some example");
    document.add(new Header("Test", "test"));
    document.open();
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Hello World");
    document.add(p);
    document.close();
}
```

As you can see, iText had `addX()` methods to add Title, Author,... metadata. However, if you want to add a custom entry, you need to use the `add()` method to add a `Header` instance. You need to add the metadata *before* opening the document.

If you want to add entries to the info dictionary of an existing PDF, you can take an example from my [book](http://itextpdf.com/book), for instance [MetadataPdf](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=216):

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    Map<String, String> info = reader.getInfo();
    info.put("Title", "Hello World stamped");
    info.put("Subject", "Hello World with changed metadata");
    info.put("Keywords", "iText in Action, PdfStamper");
    info.put("Creator", "Silly standalone example");
    info.put("Author", "Also Bruno Lowagie");
    stamper.setMoreInfo(info);
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

In this example, we get the info dictionary from a `PdfReader` instance using the `getInfo()` method.

This also answers how to retrieve the custom data from a PDF. If the `Map` contains an entry with key `Test`, you can get its value like this:

```
String test = info.get("Test");
```

You can now add extra pairs of `String`s to this `Map`.
In the example, we add standard keys for metadata, but you can also use custom keys.

Removing an entry from an existing PDF file is done in the same way as adding an entry. It's sufficient to add a `null` value. For instance:

```
info.put("Test", null);
```

This will remove a custom entry named `Test` in case such a value was present in your Info dictionary.

Comment: May I ask the code to retrieve the string pair back, suppose what i  save in the custom property is Name(Test) and Value(test), and i know the Name is Test, How to get back the Value? Thanks

Comment: Another thing is when i hash the pdf before i add the custom property (Test, test), i get string a.

Comment: However, when i use the method info.put("Test", null) to delete the Custom property. After deleting custom property, I hash again the pdf, get another string b. These 2 string are not the same. How can I make they get the same hash result? The hash algorithm i use MD5

Comment: Do not use the comments to ask extra questions. Regarding the hashing: if you read ISO-32000-1, you should know that no two PDFs are equal. If you update a PDF to add something, an ID is changed. If you update a PDF to remove that some time, the ID is changed once more. However: it is never changed into the original ID (that ID is lost). Moreover: it is inherent to PDF that the way objects are organized is random. Your use case using hashes goes against the PDF standard.

Comment: Okay, Thanks a lot! Next time i will not ask extra question in comments.

Comment: I was answering your question proposing a workaround. Then suddenly you deleted your question. Why? Aren't you interested in hearing about a workaround? Please undelete your question! (That is: if you want to solve your problem.)